# Web Api passing a list as a URL paramater issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

One of the methods that I am calling requires a list to function. Therefore I need to pass an list of values into the URL when calling the method.

I have found a few similar questions online but none of the solutions seem to be working for me.

The following is the method signature I am currently using:

```
public List<StationPlace> PlacesList(string[] list) {
```

And these are a few of the ways I have been trying to specify the list in the URL:

```
? list = "x", "y"
? list = ["x", "y"]
? list = new string[] {"x", "y"}
```

Really just guessing at this point.

Whenever I debug list is null in the execution.

Thanks.

P.S. Is there also a way to pass values in for a generic list instead of an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are fairly close try changing your url to:

```
?list=x&list=y
```

That should give you a list of `["x", "y"]`

This also works for:

```
public List<StationPlace> PlacesList([FromUri] List<string> list)
```

Comment: I just tried your suggestion but list is still = null upon execution

Comment: What HTTP method are you using?

Comment: AcceptVerbs("GET", "SET")]

Comment: Try adding the `[FromUri]` annotation, see my updated answer